# C# How to optimize a simple sum?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I'm trying to add to numbers the user input in a textBox. The operation is rather simple, but I'm asked to optimize the code the best it can. So far I have created a method where I validate if the textBox is empty or not. Then I have a method for converting the Strings from the textBox into "int". However, now I don't know how to obtain those numbers and use them in my "sum" method. Perhaps I'm forgetting something basic.

Here's my code:

```
private void btnSum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String num1 = txtNum1.Text;
    String num2 = txtNum2.Text;    

    if(validate(num1,num2) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty fields");
    }
    else 
    {
       convertNum(num1, num2);    
       MessageBox.Show("The sum is: ");   
    }
}


public static Boolean validate(String n1, String n2) 
{
    if (n1 == null || n1.Equals("") || n2 == null || n2.Equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void convertNum(String n1,String n2) 
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    try 
    {
        num1 = Int32.Parse(n1);
        num2 = Int32.Parse(n2);       
    }catch(FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input only numbers.");   
    }                
}

public static int sum(int n1, int n2) 
{
    int sum = n1 + n2;
    return sum;    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"?  You mean "make faster" or "reduce code"?

Comment: It's better to use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` and catching the exception.

Comment: Turning most operations into methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it would be much simpiler to just do all the logic in your button click method.  All your validation really needs to do is check if the text values can be parsed into integers.  `int.TryParse` will return false for null, empty string, and a string that is not a valid integer, so that's all you really need.

```
private void btnSum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int n1, n2;
    if(int.TryParse(txtNum1.Text, out n1) && int.TryParse(txtNum2.Text, out n2))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The sum is: " + (n1 + n2));
    }
    else 
    {      
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you could change your "validate" function from this:

```
public static Boolean validate(String n1, String n2) 
{
    if (n1 == null || n1.Equals("") || n2 == null || n2.Equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

...to this:

```
public static Boolean validate(String n1, String n2) 
{
    return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n1)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n2)));
}
```

...and this line:

```
if(validate(num1,num2) == false)
```

...could be:

```
if (!validate(num1,num2))
```

Comment: These are certainly good suggestions, but you haven't answered the core question of how to get the parsed ints or the sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnSum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
String num1 = txtNum1.Text;
String num2 = txtNum2.Text;    

if(validate(num1,num2) == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Empty fields");
}
else 
{
  var result  =  convertNum(num1, num2);    
   MessageBox.Show("The sum is: "+result);   
}
}

public static int convertNum(String n1,String n2) 
{
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;    
int result = 0;
try 
{
    num1 = Int32.Parse(n1);
    num2 = Int32.Parse(n2);  
    result = sum(num1,num2); 
    return result;
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input only numbers.");   
    return result; 
}     

}

public static int sum(int n1, int n2) 
{
int sum = n1 + n2;
return sum;    
}
```

Comment: result is not being returned on every part of the method. Should it be declared on top?

Comment: If the parsing fails this is going to put up one message box that says "Input only numbers." and then another that says "The sum is: 0".